# Second User on MacBook can't access downloads used by the Administrator

Tags: macbook, file-permissions, parental-controls

I am the Administrator on the MacBook, which we have all been using.  I have set up a user account for my son so I can use parental controls.  He had downloaded a few things in the administrator user and now cannot access them from his user.  Is there someway that I can share these downloads with him?

Answer (score 1):

If he downloaded them and you just want to move them over to his account, it's fairly simple. While you're logged in (as administrator) just copy the files over to his user account (Macintosh HD -> Users -> YourSon -> Documents or whatnot).

If you need a more complex solution you'll need to modify the permissions levels of a given folder, to allow his user account access to the files. If you don't need the files in the Administrator account, though, it's easiest just to move them over to his.